# What muscles are targeted by this rehab exercise? Trying to find an alternative with higher resistance

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, rehabilitation

I hurt my back a couple of months ago, and began having pain in an area between by spine and my left shoulder blade. By pure chance I discovered an exercise last week which immensely relieves the pain. I was looking to perhaps try to find a way to turn it into a progression by increasing resistance, but the current way I'm doing it doesn't seem offer possibility for higher resistance, so I'm looking for an alternative exercise that uses the same muscles and offers the possibility to increase resistance.

The exercise: kneel down on sandals and position yourself as if you were about to do a kneeling pushup (i.e. the type of push ups recommended to beginners before progressing to a full push up), and stay in the lowered position (i.e., you begin to do a half push up, you lower yourself, but you don't push back up). Now, instead of pushing yourself back up, you push yourself so as to make yourself slide on your sandals. So, instead of pushing so as to distance your chest from the ground, you push upwards so as to distance your knees from your hands (making them slide on the sandals), until your arms are extended as far as they go above your head.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

EDIT: Added an image on paint. The top picture is the initial position, the bottom picture is the position after pushing yourself away.

[image]

Comment: What you're talking about sounds like wall slides https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N73AnUp3m2w

Comment: @DarkHippo oh, you're right! the motion is very similar. the exercise I'm talking about looks like that movement with a pushing element added -- you're doing the same sort of movement as in that linked video but you're pushing yourself against the ground to make yourself slide away

Comment: I've simultaneously posted this question on the bodyweight fitness subreddit, and have received plenty of helpful responses. See https://old.reddit.com/r/bodyweightfitness/comments/w20g5n/what_muscles_are_targeted_by_this_rehab_exercise/ if this is of any interest to any reader!